# Postfix: Transport for Email Forwarding

Tags: postfix

I've a Postfix setup with virtual users running just fine. Some of my users redirect their email to external email gmail accounts, for example: `user.a@example.org` is forwarded to `userxpto@gmail.com` for their own convenience via `virtual_alias_maps`.

Now I tried to use `transport_maps` to have a dedicated transport for those forwardings like so:

**main.cf:**

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-mailbox-maps.cf
default_transport = out-default
transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/virtual/mysql-transport-maps.cf
```

**master.cf:**

```
out-default   unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
 -o proxy_interfaces=$smtp_default_transport_proxy_interface
 -o smtp_bind_address=$smtp_default_transport_interfaces
 -o inet_interfaces=$smtp_default_transport_interfaces
 -o myhostname=$smtp_default_transport_hostname
 -o smtp_helo_name=$smtp_default_transport_hostname
 -o syslog_name=smtp-$smtp_default_transport_hostname
out-fwd   unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
 -o proxy_interfaces=$smtp_default_transport_proxy_interface
 -o smtp_bind_address=$smtp_default_transport_interfaces
 -o inet_interfaces=$smtp_default_transport_interfaces
 -o myhostname=$smtp_default_transport_hostname
 -o smtp_helo_name=$smtp_default_transport_hostname
 -o syslog_name=smtp-fwd-$smtp_default_transport_hostname
 -o bounce_queue_lifetime=0
 -o maximal_queue_lifetime=0
```

**mysql-alias-maps.cf:**

```
query = SELECT destination FROM `aliases` WHERE source='%s'
```

**mysql-transport-maps.cf:**

```
query = SELECT IF (ISNULL(destination), NULL, 'out-fwd') as transport \
FROM `aliases` \
WHERE destination='%s' \
AND destination LIKE '%%@gmail.com'
```

**What I'm trying to accomplish is "if the user has their email forwarded to a @gmail reduce the queue lifetime.**"

Now when I try to send and email to those users this is what happens:

```
postfix/qmgr[28839]: warning: connect to transport private/out-fwd,out-fwd: No such file or directory
```

private/out-fwd,**out-fwd** > **Why is it duplicating the name of the transport?**

If I change the query to return `out-fwd:` (colon at the end) I get:

```
smtp-fwd-xxxx/smtp[23429]: fatal: valid hostname or network address required in server description: ,out-fwd:
```

,out-fwd: ??? Why?

Note that if I simply comment the `transport_maps` line email gets delivered using `default_transport = out-default` just fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was my query. The query above would return multiple results if there was more than one local account forwarded / aliased to the same external gmail account and due to some reason Postfix would concatenate the results.

```
query = SELECT IF (ISNULL(destination), NULL, 'out-fwd') as transport \
FROM `aliases` \
WHERE destination='%s' \
AND destination LIKE '%%@gmail.com' \
LIMIT 1
```

Adding the `LIMIT` fixed the problem.